# iPhone http post request fields and values

Tags: php, iphone, http-post

I need to get JSON from a .php, I need help knowing how to fill in the fields required as I have not done this before and really don't fully understand the .php page.  Here is the details on the .php link

```
jQuery(function($){

function get_current_show() {
//Get the current show data
$.post(crudScriptURL, {"crud-action" : "read", "read-type" : "current"}, function (currentShowJSON) {

    var schedule = $.parseJSON(currentShowJSON);
    var outputHTML = '';

    var currentShow = schedule['current-show'];
    if (currentShow.showName){
        var currentShowName = currentShow.showName;
        var imageURL = currentShow.imageURL;
        var linkURL = currentShow.linkURL;
        var startClock = currentShow.startClock;
        var endClock = currentShow.endClock;

        if (linkURL){
            currentShowName = '<a href="'+linkURL+'">'+currentShowName+'</a>';
        }



        outputHTML += '<h3 class="current-show">'+currentShowName+'</h3>';
        outputHTML += '<span>'+startClock + ' - ' + endClock + '</span>';

        if (imageURL){
            if (linkURL){
                outputHTML += '<a href="'+linkURL+'"><img class="showtime-image-thumbnail" src="'+imageURL+'" alt="'+currentShow.showName+'" /></a>';
            } else {
                outputHTML += '<img class="showtime-image-thumbnail" src="'+imageURL+'" alt="'+currentShow.showName+'" />';
            }
        }

    } else {

        outputHTML += '<h3 class="current-show">'+currentShow+'<h3>';

    }

    var upcomingShow = schedule['upcoming-show'];
    if (upcomingShow){
        var upcomingShowName = upcomingShow.showName;
        var upcomingShowLink = upcomingShow.linkURL;
        var upcomingStartClock = upcomingShow.startClock;
        var upcomingEndClock = upcomingShow.endClock;

        if (upcomingShowLink){
            outputHTML += '<h3 class="upcoming-show"><strong>Up next:</strong> <a href="'+upcomingShowLink+'">'+upcomingShowName+'</a></h3>';
        } else {
            outputHTML += '<h3 class="upcoming-show"><strong>Up next:</strong> '+upcomingShowName+'</h3>';
        }

        outputHTML += '<span>'+upcomingStartClock + ' - ' + upcomingEndClock + '</span>';

    }

    $('.showtime-now-playing').html(outputHTML);

    //Set a timer to update the widget every 30 seconds
    setTimeout (get_current_show, (30 * 1000));

});

}

get_current_show();


});
```

And here is what I am trying

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://selectukradio.com/wp-content/plugins/showtime/showtime.js"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"crud-action" forHTTPHeaderField:@"read"];
[request setValue:@"read-type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"current"];
[request setValue:@"http://selectukradio.com/wp-content/plugins/showtime/crud.php" forHTTPHeaderField:@"currentShowJSON"];
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);

    //here you get the response
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
The response that I am getting in my log is

```
2014-02-21 22:06:47.510 request[579:70b] Response Code: 200
2014-02-21 22:06:47.511 request[579:70b] Response: jQuery(function($){

function get_current_show() {
//Get the current show data
$.post(crudScriptURL, {"crud-action" : "read", "read-type" : "current"}, function (currentShowJSON) {

    var schedule = $.parseJSON(currentShowJSON);
    var outputHTML = '';

    var currentShow = schedule['current-show'];
    if (currentShow.showName){
        var currentShowName = currentShow.showName;
        var imageURL = currentShow.imageURL;
        var linkURL = currentShow.linkURL;
        var startClock = currentShow.startClock;
        var endClock = currentShow.endClock;

        if (linkURL){
            currentShowName = '<a href="'+linkURL+'">'+currentShowName+'</a>';
        }



        outputHTML += '<h3 class="current-show">'+currentShowName+'</h3>';
        outputHTML += '<span>'+startClock + ' - ' + endClock + '</span>';

        if (imageURL){
            if (linkURL){
                outputHTML += '<a href="'+linkURL+'"><img class="showtime-image-thumbnail" src="'+imageURL+'" alt="'+currentShow.showName+'" /></a>';
            } else {
                outputHTML += '<img class="showtime-image-thumbnail" src="'+imageURL+'" alt="'+currentShow.showName+'" />';
            }
        }

    } else {

        outputHTML += '<h3 class="current-show">'+currentShow+'<h3>';

    }

    var upcomingShow = schedule['upcoming-show'];
    if (upcomingShow){
        var upcomingShowName = upcomingShow.showName;
        var upcomingShowLink = upcomingShow.linkURL;
        var upcomingStartClock = upcomingShow.startClock;
        var upcomingEndClock = upcomingShow.endClock;

        if (upcomingShowLink){
            outputHTML += '<h3 class="upcoming-show"><strong>Up next:</strong> <a href="'+upcomingShowLink+'">'+upcomingShowName+'</a></h3>';
        } else {
            outputHTML += '<h3 class="upcoming-show"><strong>Up next:</strong> '+upcomingShowName+'</h3>';
        }

        outputHTML += '<span>'+upcomingStartClock + ' - ' + upcomingEndClock + '</span>';

    }

    $('.showtime-now-playing').html(outputHTML);

    //Set a timer to update the widget every 30 seconds
    setTimeout (get_current_show, (30 * 1000));

});

}

get_current_show();


});
```

I need to get the currentShow.imageURL and currentShow.showName etc etc
The source code of the web page shows this

```
<script>crudScriptURL = "http://selectukradio.com/wp-content/plugins/showtime/crud.php"</script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://selectukradio.com/wp-content/plugins/showtime/showtime.js" ></script>
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem you are encountering? Also, can you explain what the different files are? How does the JavaScript file get run, if the Objective C code calls the PHP file directly?

Comment: I am not getting the JSON as the result, instead I am getting the details of the .php page.  What I need to get is the currnetShow.imageURL etc

Comment: "instead I am getting the details of the .php page" - what are "the details"?

Comment: OK, I think you're getting your question in a pickle here. I suggest you edit your question and add your various responses in, taking care to explain what each thing is. Code doesn't display very well in comments, and it is best to construct entirely self-contained questions anyway, so people don't have to wade through made comments to find out the status of a question. Once you've done that, delete the redundant comments, and you'll have a better question!

Comment: I am guessing that you should not be referring to `showtime.js` in your Objective C code at all. This is a plain text file containing JavaScript, suitable only as a web page asset. You need a dynamic server-side page to generate JSON responses - perhaps `setURL` should be passed the `crud.php` link instead?

Comment: A good approach might be to find out how to get your JSON first - check if it really is a POST method, and what the target URL should be. Consult the documentation for this web service for this. Then check it using a simple tool - I think `wget` on the command line can issue POST requests.

Comment: thank you, I will try this and post any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using AFNetworking, below is the code to help anyone else

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://selectukradio.com/wp-content/plugins/showtime/crud.php";
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"crud-action" : @"read", @"read-type" : @"current"};
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a dictionary");


        for (NSString *key in [responseObject allKeys])
        {
            NSDictionary *feed = [responseObject objectForKey:key];
            NSString *name = [feed objectForKey:@"showName"];
            NSString *final = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
            NSString *image = [feed objectForKey:@"imageURL"];
            [names addObject:final];
            [images addObject:image];
            //do stuff with feed.
        }
        NSLog(@" First dj: %@",[names objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@" First dj image: %@", [images objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"Next up dj: %@", [names objectAtIndex:1]);
        NSLog(@"Next dj image: %@", [images objectAtIndex:1]);


    }

 //   NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```